# Irregular Time- Calculating Unique Minutes based off Start and Stop Times

Tags: r

I've just recently started diving into learning R and I'm also trying to see if it can help me with a work problem I'm having calculating Employee Utilization.

I am trying to calculate the minutes clocked to labor for each employee for each day and then I'm dividing that by their total minutes clocked in for the day. The total clocked minutes is easy to get but the labor is tricky because the only data I'm given is the employee and their start and stop times for labor. I'm wrestling with how I can make sure I don't double up minutes worked.

I've thrown together some dummy data below. What would be the best way to go about summing up the total minutes they were clocked to *something* for the day? It gets tricky because they clock to multiple things at once, and they don't necessarily stop all at the same time. So you end up with a lot of overlap that you need to remove.

I wrestled with this in HANA/SQL. I ended up doing an ugly deal where I created a table that had a record for each minute of the day and then did a cross-join and aggregated from there, but I ran into some issues there with 3rd shift folks who span days.

Wondering if there is something I could do with R that might help.

```
Employee    Start                   Stop
Eddie       8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 10:45:00 AM
Eddie       8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 10:57:00 AM
Eddie       8/21/2017 6:57:00 AM    8/21/2017 11:27:00 AM
Eddie       8/21/2017 11:58:00 AM   8/21/2017 12:57:00 PM
Joe         8/21/2017 5:38:00 AM    8/21/2017 7:00:00 AM
Joe         8/21/2017 5:38:00 AM    8/21/2017 7:00:00 AM
Joe         8/21/2017 7:46:00 AM    8/21/2017 9:11:00 AM
Joe         8/21/2017 7:46:00 AM    8/21/2017 9:12:00 AM
Joe         8/21/2017 9:52:00 AM    8/21/2017 12:35:00 PM
Joe         8/21/2017 9:52:00 AM    8/21/2017 12:40:00 PM
Joe         8/21/2017 11:46:00 AM   8/21/2017 1:46:00 PM
```

To clarify, the issue I'm having isn't summing up their work for the day and breaking it out by employee, the issue is of instances where they have multiple rows that overlap time. I want to make sure each minute of the day is only counted once.

In the example above for instance Eddie he has 4 records, but three of these overlap. What I need is a way to logically say, Eddie was clocked on to something from 6:57 AM to 11:27 AM. Count the minutes between those two times and then pick up his last clocking which has no overlap (11:58 AM to 12:57). Hopefully that makes sense. This is an oddball time problem that I've never had to fight before.

Answer (score 0):

Using base R:

```
dt[['duration']] <- as.numeric(difftime(dt$Stop, dt$Start), units = 'mins')
splitDt <- split(dt$duration, dt$Employee)
sapply(splitDt, sum)
```

Using `dplyr` package:

library(dplyr)

```
dt %>%
  group_by(Employee) %>%
  summarize(totalDuration = sum(duration))
```

You need to calculate the duration with `difftime` and convert to the correct units. Then you can group or split the data by employee.

To not over count minutes you can do the following:

```
splitDt <- split(dt, dt$Employee)
seqMin <- mapply(seq, dt$Start, dt$Stop, by = 'min', SIMPLIFY = FALSE)
sapply(unique(dt$Employee), function(employee) {
  i <- grep(employee, dt$Employee)
  length(unique(unlist(seqMin[i])))
})
```

Create the sequences of minutes and then combine all minutes together. Counting the distinct time intervals will provide the desired output.

Comment: Thanks troh! The problem I have though is that I can't sum up the durations to get my answer. If I sum up that way I'll end up with a higher number of minutes, because they could have overlapping times. I need to ensure every actual "minute" of the clock is only counted once. Confusing, and I didn't make it clear enough originally so I've edited my original post. Appreciate the help.